# how to add hour to pandas dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe time column like following.

```
 segments_data['time']
 Out[1585]: 
 0      04:50:00
 1      04:50:00
 2      05:00:00
 3      05:12:00
 4      06:04:00
 5      06:44:00
 6      06:44:00
 7      06:47:00
 8      06:47:00
 9      06:47:00
```

I want to add 5 hours and 30 mins to above time column. 
I am doing following in python.

```
pd.DatetimeIndex(segments_data['time']) + pd.DateOffset(hours=5,minutes=30)
```

But it gives me an error.

```python
TypeError: object of type 'datetime.time' has no len()
```

please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a gnarly way of doing it, principally the problem here is the lack of vectorised support for `time` objects, so you first need to convert the `time` to `datetime` by using `combine` and then apply the offset and get the `time` component back:

```
In [28]:  
import datetime as dt  
df['new_time'] = df['time'].apply(lambda x: (dt.datetime.combine(dt.datetime(1,1,1), x,) + dt.timedelta(hours=3,minutes=30)).time())
df

Out[28]:
           time  new_time
index                    
0      04:50:00  08:20:00
1      04:50:00  08:20:00
2      05:00:00  08:30:00
3      05:12:00  08:42:00
4      06:04:00  09:34:00
5      06:44:00  10:14:00
6      06:44:00  10:14:00
7      06:47:00  10:17:00
8      06:47:00  10:17:00
9      06:47:00  10:17:00
```

Comment: How to select time greater than 10am in above?

Comment: `df[df['new_time'] > dt.time(10,0)]` works for me or `df[df.new_time.gt(dt.time(10))]`

Answer (score 18):

as of '0.25.3' this is as simple as

```
df[column] = df[column] + pd.Timedelta(hours=1)
```

Answer (score 8):

You can try importing `timedelta`:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
```

and then:

```
segments_data['time'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(segments_data['time']) + timedelta(hours=5,minutes=30)
```

Answer (score 4):

Pandas does not support vectorised operations with `datetime.time` objects. For efficient, vectorised operations, there is no requirement to use the `datetime` module from the standard library.

You have a couple of options to vectorise your calculation. Either use a *Pandas* `timedelta` series, if your times represent a duration. Or use a *Pandas* `datetime` series, if your times represent specific points in time.

The choice depends entirely on what your data represents.

#### `timedelta` series

```
df['time'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['time'].astype(str)) + pd.to_timedelta('05:30:00')

print(df['time'].head())

0   10:20:00
1   10:20:00
2   10:30:00
3   10:42:00
4   11:34:00
Name: 1, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

#### `datetime` series

```
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'].astype(str)) + pd.DateOffset(hours=5, minutes=30)

print(df['time'].head())

0   2018-12-24 10:20:00
1   2018-12-24 10:20:00
2   2018-12-24 10:30:00
3   2018-12-24 10:42:00
4   2018-12-24 11:34:00
Name: 1, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Notice by default the *current* date is assumed.

Comment: Interesting - how does this compare to the approach in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35033280/281545) answer. Should we prefer `pd.to_timedelta` and co over `pd.DatetimeIndex` ?

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D, No time complexity difference. They should be roughly equivalent. In general, I reserve `DatetimeIndex` when I'm creating an index (since it's in the name), `to_datetime` when creating a series.