# Update a specific position in a column of a pandas dataframe based on some condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

For example, one of my column of my dataframe has data like below:

```
29-APR-19 11.50.00.000000000 PM

29-APR-19 11.50.00.000000000 AM
```

Hence, I need to update the column having PM to:

```
29-APR-19 23.50.00.000000000 PM
```

How can we do that?

I have tried formatting the column to specific date format types, but not able to find the solution.

Comment: does this one help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35032135/how-to-add-hour-to-pandas-dataframe-column , is your column a datetime column? you can chage it with `df.dytpes`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19229190/convert-12-hour-into-24-hour-times

Comment: Convert to `datetime` type for easier control over formatting. In your case use `pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'], format='%d-%b-%y %I.%M.%S.%f %p')`. Then use `df['datetime'].dt.strftime('%d-%b-%y %H.%M.%S.%f %p')`

Comment: @ChrisA solution is the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

If need same format here is necessary add `12` hours for datetimes below `12:00:00`.

Solution is first convert column by [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html), then add `12` hours by condition and for same format use [`Series.dt.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html):

```
print (df)
                              Date
0  29-APR-19 11.50.00.000000000 PM
1  29-APR-19 11.50.00.000000000 AM

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%d-%b-%y %I.%M.%S.%f %p') 
df.loc[df['Date'].dt.hour < 12] += pd.Timedelta(12, 'h')

df['Date'] = df['Date'].dt.strftime('%d-%b-%y %I.%M.%S.%f %p')
print (df)

                           Date
0  29-Apr-19 11.50.00.000000 PM
1  29-Apr-19 11.50.00.000000 PM
```

Comment: Don't think this is what the OP wants - think just update 'PM' to 24 hour format

Comment: ya, it is possible, but `df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%d-%b-%y %I.%M.%S.%f %p').dt.strftime('%d-%b-%y %I.%M.%S.%f %p')` not working - get same output...

Comment: needs `'%H'` for 24 hour - in `strftime` method